# How to interact JQuery slider with d3 vertical lines for every data point

Tags: jquery, d3.js, jquery-ui-slider

I am trying to create an interactive slider zooming and filtering into a data range using vertical line from each data point selected.  I am not sure how to draw every vertical lines on each data point so the slider can zoom and filter vertical lines on this data range. Currently, I can draw circles on every data point and one vertical line (see attached output graph), but would like to draw vertical lines on top of those circles or just for each data point if d3 has some way to do it. I am new to d3 and I will appreciate your feedback!  Here is what I have so far learning from other useful sites.

```js
/* implementation heavily influenced by http://bl.ocks.org/1166403 */

// define dimensions of graph
var m = [80, 80, 80, 80]; // margins
var w = 1000 - m[1] - m[3]; // width
var h = 350 - m[0] - m[2]; // height

// create a simple data array that we'll plot with a line (this array represents only the Y values, X will just be the index location)
var data = [0];
for (var i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
  var sign = Math.random() > 0.5 ? +1 : -1;
  data.push(data[i - 1] + sign * Math.random());
}

// X scale will fit all values from data[] within pixels 0-w
var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, data.length]).range([0, w]);
// Y scale will fit values from 0-10 within pixels h-0 (Note the inverted domain for the y-scale: bigger is up!)
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([d3.min(data), d3.max(data)]).range([h, 0]);

// Add an SVG element with the desired dimensions and margin.
var graph = d3.select("#graph").append("svg:svg")
  .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
  .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
  .append("svg:g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");

// create yAxis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).tickSize(-h).tickSubdivide(3);
// Add the x-axis.
graph.append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

// create left yAxis
var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).ticks(4).orient("left");
// Add the y-axis to the left
graph.append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(-25,0)")
  .call(yAxisLeft);

var clip = graph.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("svg:rect")
  .attr("id", "clip-rect")
  .attr("x", "0")
  .attr("y", "0")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);


var circle = graph.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data);

circle.enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
    return x(i)
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return y(d)
  })
  .attr("class", "circle")
  .attr("r", 2)
  .attr("fill", "red");

var verticalLine = graph.append('line')
  .attr({
    'x1': 0,
    'y1': 0,
    'x2': 0,
    'y2': h
  })
  .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
  .attr('class', 'verticalLine');

function zoom(begin, end) {
  x.domain([begin, end - 1]);

  var t = graph.transition().duration(0);

  var size = end - begin;
  var step = size / 10;
  var ticks = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    ticks.push(Math.floor(begin + step * i));
  }

  xAxis.tickValues(ticks);

  t.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  t.select('.path').attr("d", verticalLine(data));
}

$(function() {
  $("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 1000,
    values: [0, 1000],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      var begin = d3.min([ui.values[0], data.length]);
      var end = d3.max([ui.values[1], 0]);
      console.log("begin:", begin, "end:", end);

      zoom(begin, end);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* tell the SVG path to be a thin blue line without any area fill */

path {
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1;
  fill: none;
}

.axis {
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis line {
  stroke: lightgrey;
}

.x.axis .minor {
  stroke-opacity: .5;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.y.axis line,
.y.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.v2.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<div id="graph" class="aGraph"></div>
<div id="slider-range" style="width: 80%px; margin-left:10%; margin-right:10%"></div>
```

Output
[image: graph]

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more what is your intention with the range slider and the vertical lines. Does [this](https://observablehq.com/@bumbeishvili/data-driven-range-sliders) notebook has the implementation you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I very highly recommend upgrading your d3 version. v6 is out now, v5 will be supported and popular for a long time, but v2 has become very obscure

Comment: @RicardoSanchez, yes I am trying to accomplish the first graph with frequency data with those red lines on that data posted on that notebook link.

Comment: @RubenHelsloot, unfortunately I can't update as I wish so I am stuck with this v2

Comment: thank you @RubenHelsloot for those vertical lines of below code, was not bad after all, just complains about verticalLine is not a function when using the zooming in the slider ... if I change the last line of the zoom function to t.select('.path').attr("d", verticalLine); then the zooming in the slider takes in the x-values as a range... which is what I need! :)

Comment: I looked into the issue deeper and switched changes from what I said previously with ``t.select('.path').attr("d", verticalLine);`` The verticalLine with data doesn't move with the slider, the slider only moves the xAxis range without the data :( any good suggestions? @RubenHelsloot

Comment: Look at `d3-zoom`. There is not even a need to use jQuery. If you need more information, please ask a new question

Comment: @RubenHelsloot, Hum yeah I can't even use d3-zoom :( I have looked as well, stuck with jquery.

Comment: I will ask a new question for sure! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the lines, just repeat what you did with the circles one more time.

```js
/* implementation heavily influenced by http://bl.ocks.org/1166403 */

// define dimensions of graph
var m = [80, 80, 80, 80]; // margins
var w = 1000 - m[1] - m[3]; // width
var h = 350 - m[0] - m[2]; // height

// create a simple data array that we'll plot with a line (this array represents only the Y values, X will just be the index location)
var data = [0];
for (var i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
  var sign = Math.random() > 0.5 ? +1 : -1;
  data.push(data[i - 1] + sign * Math.random());
}

// X scale will fit all values from data[] within pixels 0-w
var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, data.length]).range([0, w]);
// Y scale will fit values from 0-10 within pixels h-0 (Note the inverted domain for the y-scale: bigger is up!)
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([d3.min(data), d3.max(data)]).range([h, 0]);

// Add an SVG element with the desired dimensions and margin.
var graph = d3.select("#graph").append("svg:svg")
  .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
  .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
  .append("svg:g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");

// create yAxis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).tickSize(-h).tickSubdivide(3);
// Add the x-axis.
graph.append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

// create left yAxis
var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).ticks(4).orient("left");
// Add the y-axis to the left
graph.append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(-25,0)")
  .call(yAxisLeft);

var clip = graph.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("svg:rect")
  .attr("id", "clip-rect")
  .attr("x", "0")
  .attr("y", "0")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);


var circle = graph.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data);

circle.enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
    return x(i)
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return y(d)
  })
  .attr("class", "circle")
  .attr("r", 2)
  .attr("fill", "red");

var verticalLine = graph.selectAll(".vertical-line")
  .data(data);

verticalLine.enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("x1", function(d, i) {
    return x(i)
  })
  .attr("x2", function(d, i) {
    return x(i)
  })
  .attr({
    y1: 0,
    y2: h,
    stroke: 'steelblue',
    class: 'vertical-line'
  });

function zoom(begin, end) {
  x.domain([begin, end - 1]);

  var t = graph.transition().duration(0);

  var size = end - begin;
  var step = size / 10;
  var ticks = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    ticks.push(Math.floor(begin + step * i));
  }

  xAxis.tickValues(ticks);

  t.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  t.select('.path').attr("d", verticalLine(data));
}

$(function() {
  $("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 1000,
    values: [0, 1000],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      var begin = d3.min([ui.values[0], data.length]);
      var end = d3.max([ui.values[1], 0]);
      console.log("begin:", begin, "end:", end);

      zoom(begin, end);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* tell the SVG path to be a thin blue line without any area fill */

path {
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1;
  fill: none;
}

.axis {
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis line {
  stroke: lightgrey;
}

.x.axis .minor {
  stroke-opacity: .5;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.y.axis line,
.y.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.v2.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<div id="graph" class="aGraph"></div>
<div id="slider-range" style="width: 80%px; margin-left:10%; margin-right:10%"></div>
```